# Jumbotron BG image resizeable, wont show up

Tags: html, css

might be a stupid question but i am trying to fix my Jumbotron header with a bgimage..it did work before but the image was squished when resized..found a workaround but now it kinda doesnt show up anymore :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 jumbotron" id="jumbotronBG">
            <div class="text-center">
                  <h1>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</h1>
                  <a href="#services" class="btn btn-md btn-danger">SERVICES</a>
                  <a href="#companies" class="btn btn-md btn-success">COMPANIES</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
 .jumbotronBG {
  background: url('../img/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 350px !important; /*same height as jumbotron */
  top:0 !important;
  left:0 !important;
  z-index: -1 !important;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 40px !important;
  height: 350px !important;
  color: white !important;
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.3em 0.3em !important;
  background:transparent !important;

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me :-)

Comment: Change `.jumbotronBG` to `#jumbotronBG` in your css and see what happens.

Comment: just realized the misstake and tried it but unfortuantly it lets everything colapse and still no bg image..i think i had it before no clue what i destroyed..thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add your background url to .jumbotron class.

html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 jumbotron">
        <div class="text-center">
              <h1>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</h1>
              <a href="#services" class="btn btn-md btn-danger">SERVICES</a>
              <a href="#companies" class="btn btn-md btn-success">COMPANIES</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 40px !important;
  color: white !important;
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.3em 0.3em !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eaxzjmmk/

Comment: thanks a lot...there was a weird cloud9 error..everytime i changed it and refreshed the preview it just showed up for a second and went away then..it works perfect now..thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1):

You have a .jumbotronBG class in  your CSS, but you are not using it in your HTML.

Just change your ".jumbotronBG" class definition in your CSS file to this: "#jumbotronBG" and the styles will be applied correctly.

You could also put the background style inside the ".jumbotron" class definition, but if you use more than one jumbotron in your project, all them will have the same customized background and that may not be your desired behavior.